# C# from loaded Dll call GetType of a static class in the main exe

Tags: c#, exception, reflection

I have the `main.exe` loads a dll, from the loaded dll, I try to get the static class defined in the main exe so the code in dll project will be:

```
static class DllClass
{
    static DllClass()
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(); // line 1
        Type type = assembly.GetType("StaticClass");    //line 2
    }
}
```

however, line 2 gives me the following exception

> *System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'DllClass' threw an exception. --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'DllClass' threw an exception. ---> System.NullReferenceException:
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

I think the problem here is static class StatisClass somehow wasn't found in the runtime and return null.

Any ideas how to resolve it?

Answer (score 3):

With the code above there can only be one reason: your `assembly` variable is `NULL`. So when can this happen? According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly.aspx) there is only one case:

> The GetEntryAssembly method can return NULL when a managed assembly has been loaded from an unmanaged application. For example, if an unmanaged application creates an instance of a COM component written in C#, a call to the GetEntryAssembly method from the C# component returns NULL, because the entry point for the process was unmanaged code rather than a managed assembly.

In this case the answer by @Beachwalker wouldn't work either. Also if you are dynamically loading types, the code would not even compile.

Comment: yes, saw this at the same time after my first post after reading the documentation again (+1).

Comment: well, the dll project was built on Visual Studio 2012 with .net 2.0 framework, so the dll code is actually managed code.

Comment: so I finally tried to get Assembly form CurrentDomain by calling AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies(), and it does return me a non-null assembly.

Comment: It does not matter whether or not the assembly hosting your "DllClass" code is managed - the assembly starting the process must be managed (your "main.exe").

Answer (score 1):

When using reflection, the type can only be retrieved using the fullname.
i.e., including the "Namespace" along with the class name.

So, change line 2 as below and it will work:

```
Type type = assembly.GetType("NamespaceName.StaticClass");    //line 2
```

Comment: Basicly true, but a wrong type identifier leads to an null-reference for the variable "type" which means that the code would throw an exception in the following lines, not in "line 2". ;-)

Comment: I am assuming you already know the type (atleast the type being non-abstract) and don't want to end up with a null-reference. Otherwise, there is no point in using this kind of code.

Comment: Sorry for the changes:
`private MyStaticClass GetMyClass()
        {
            string fooClassName = "MyStaticClass";
            MyStaticClass sClass = null;
            try
            {
                Type type = Type.GetType(fooClassName);
                if (type == null)
                    type = Type.GetType("MyNamespace." + fooClassName);
                if (type != null)
                {
                    sClass = (MyStaticClass)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                }
            }
            catch block here...
            
            return sClass;
        }`

Comment: You got me wrong. The question states "however, line 2 gives me the following exception". Line 2 throws an NullReferenceException, which means the assembly could not be loaded, before. It does not matter if he knows the type or not ;-)

Comment: the static class StaticClass in exe project is under global namespace, so the way I used to GetType is correct?

Answer (score 0):

What about just using the following:

```
Type t = typeof(StaticClass)
```

Maybe you're getting the NullReferenceException because of this:

"The GetEntryAssembly method can return a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) when a managed assembly has been loaded from an unmanaged application. For example, if an unmanaged application creates an instance of a COM component written in C#, a call to the GetEntryAssembly method from the C# component returns null, because the entry point for the process was unmanaged code rather than a managed assembly."

(MSDN, http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly(v=vs.80).aspx)

=> test required:

```
if (assembly != null)
{
 ...
}
```